# background-image in MVC4 not work

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, background-image

I am using basic template for mvc 4.I want set background image for my div element.My stylesheet located in "~/Content" directory.Here is part of my .cshtml file where I am trying direct specify image without css:

```
        <div id="add_image" class ="image_bar" style="background-image:url(add.jpg)" ></div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#add_image {
    background-image:url('~/add.jpg');
}

#add_image:hover {
    background-image:url('~/addhover.jpg');
}
.image_bar {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}
```

Neither css neither direct "styling" not works - whats wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your second example, you are using the '~/' moniker, this is a .NET thing that instructs the code to look at the root of the site.  Since the .NET engine does not process your CSS file, the '~/' has no effect and probably makes a really ugly HTTP request to the server.

Since you have your CSS in your Content directory, one solution is to create a sub directory in your Content called 'images'.  Store any and all of your CSS images in that folder.  Then, from your CSS file, you can call and reference images in that file as such:

```
#add_image {
    background-image:url('images/add.jpg');
}

#add_image:hover {
    background-image:url('images/addhover.jpg');
}
```

This is assuming a directory structure like so:

- Content

  - images

    - add.jpg
    - addhover.jpg
  - site.css

Though I am not a designer, I believe that CSS will look for images relative to the location of the CSS file and not the root of the web application like HTML.  Additionally, if you stored images in the same directory as your CSS file, then you should be able to call those images without the 'images/' prefix.  However, most like to keep resources separate.

Comment: Before placing images on the root I kept them in image folder and css was exact you show.But that doesnt work.May be its my own bug.

Comment: Where was the images folder relative to the CSS file?  Also, keep that ~ out of your CSS :)

Comment: folder struct was like you shown.There was one little strange behavior I am not specify earlier - when mouse hovers expected image position it (expected image area) changes background from transparent to bright color.

Comment: It is not easy to tell exactly what the issue may be here.  There may be other CSS overriding the behavior, things that you have changed in order to make this work may be interfering, etc.  I would recommend you fire up a new project (using not the empty template) and attempt to implement what you need in a clean environment.  Additionally, check Firebug or use Chrome's developers console to look at exactly what the browser is trying to resolve (URL).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> background-image:url('~/add.jpg');

try using

> background-image:url('./add.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

try with

`background-image:url('../add.jpg')`;

Answer (score 0):

try this 
**example  -

```
background-image:url('../img/home_bg.jpg');**

background-image:url('../**ImageFolderName**/add.jpg');
```

Comment: Please add more details. Your post is being voted for deletion.

Comment: what details,whay cant understand for this?

Comment: Your answer is being voted for deletion because it is low quality